# How to resolve between conflicting function call in gdb

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I have 2 functions of same name in two different c++ files. Lets say the function name is initialize(char*) and files are file1.cpp and file2.cpp. From gdb how do I call the initialize() function of file file2.cpp. I have tried "call 'file2.cpp'::initialize("setup") but it calls function of file1.cpp.

Comment: and why `C++` tag missing? [Added it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified that same function gets called both times. 
This looks like a bug in gdb. You should [report it](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/).

This could probably be used as workaround:

1. print 'file1.cpp'::initialize
2. print 'file2.cpp'::initialize
3. (now you have addresses of both functions)
4. call address-of-one-or-other-function("setup")